# create trigger using a stored procedure

Tags: sql, ms-access, stored-procedures, triggers

I have a trigger and I want to kick it off from a stored procedure. I am using ms access and when i run the trigger from ms access it gives me an error msg (ODBC). I think I can't create triggers using ms access. This is my trigger:

```
IF EXISTS 
(SELECT name 
FROM sys.objects 
WHERE name = 'UpdateComments' AND type = 'TR')
DROP TRIGGER tblEmailHdr_abenit01.UpdateComments; 
GO 
CREATE TRIGGER UpdateComments 
ON tblEmailHdr_abenit01 
AFTER Update 
AS 
IF ( UPDATE (Comments) ) BEGIN Update ttblEmailHdr_abenit01 
Set UpdateComm = GetDate() 
END;
GO
```

This is how I have been trying to create the trigger from the stored procedure but I get the following error msg's when I try to create the sproc:

Sproc:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.SP_AS_tblEmailHdr_Trig (@UserID as varchar(10)) 
AS
BEGIN
 -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
 -- interfering with SELECT statements.
 --SET NOCOUNT ON;

-- Insert statements for procedure here
 Declare @UserTable Varchar(50)
 Declare @UserTable2 Varchar(50)

 Set @UserTable = 'tblEmailHdr_' + @UserID ;
 Set @UserTable2 = 'tblEmailHdr_' + @UserID + '.UpdateComments' ;

IF EXISTS 
 (SELECT name 
 FROM sys.objects 
 WHERE name = 'UpdateComments' AND type = 'TR') DROP TRIGGER @UserTable2   

 GO
 CREATE TRIGGER UpdateComments 
 ON @UserTable 
 AFTER UPDATE 
 AS 
 IF ( UPDATE (Comments) )
 BEGIN
  --RAISERROR (50009, 16, 10)
  Update @UserTable 
  Set UpdatedComm = GetDate() 
 END
 GO

END

GO
```

error msg i get:

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure SP_AS_tblEmailHdr_Trig, Line 23
Incorrect syntax near '@UserTable2'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure UpdateComments, Line 2
Incorrect syntax near '@UserTable'.
Msg 1087, Level 15, State 2, Procedure UpdateComments, Line 8
Must declare the table variable "@UserTable".
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
Incorrect syntax near 'END'.
```

Comment: remove the GO from inside the sp

Comment: @Vikram `GO` may be preventing the procedure from being created, but it still isn't going to result in the trigger being *executed* as the OP seems to want.

Comment: @Yuck: you are right. trigger gets executed automatically.. but i thought he is trying to create one.

Comment: I think you've either phrased your question incorrectly, or have misunderstood how triggers function.

Answer (score 0):

```
create procedure pro (parameters)
as
begin
  declare @trigs nvarchar(max)
  declare @trip nvarchar(max)
  set @trigs='
    create trigger tri on dbo.employee
    for insert
    as
      select * from inserted
    go'
  set @trip='drop trigger tri'

  EXEC sp_executeSQL @trigs

  insert into employee values(parameters)

  EXEC sp_executeSQL @trip
end

exec pro param
eg:
exec pro 80,'aaa','AAS',25000,'2013-02-01','iT'
```

Answer (score -1):

remove all the GO statements from inside the procedure.